# SQL just do the opposite of this

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

```
SELECT Name FROM Anime LEFT JOIN anime_user2 ON anime_idAnime = idAnime WHERE users_userID = $userID
```

I want to get the exact opposite of this but it's not working with

```
WHERE users_userID != $userID
```

I get 4 Names, but I want every Name except those 4 Names.

Do you how to do this?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Sorry, will do it next time. I found the answer myself, I guess I should think some time before going to this site, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` operator like this:

```
SELECT NAME
  FROM ANIME a
 WHERE a.NAME NOT IN (
    SELECT Name 
      FROM Anime LEFT JOIN anime_user2 ON anime_idAnime = idAnime 
     WHERE users_userID = $userID
 )
```

BEWARE: Depending on what is your table histogram, this query might be too slow to use it on a web page or application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't working for me.